# Given p(x) Gaussian, and p(y|x) a Gaussian, is the joint distribution p(x,y) always a Gaussian?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

It is well-known that multivariate Gaussians are closed under conditioning, but is the reverse true? Does having a Gaussian conditional with a Gaussian marginal always result in a bivariate Gaussian?

Comment: Not necessarily - consider $ Y|X = x \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1 +x^2).$

Comment: Thank you for your response, is there a quick way to see why that does not produce a bivariate gaussian? I'm not sure how you came up with that counter-example

Comment: The simplest thing seems to be to show that $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y) = 0$, but clearly $X$ and $Y$ are not independent, which violates the standard theorem that uncorrelated jointly Gaussian random variables are independent.

Comment: @stochasticboy321, this would be a good answer if you typed it up.